# Java script referrer in an Iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a shopping website that I want to put a back to previous page link on using the referrer option. I can get the java script to load the first line but it won't switch to the second when the referrer is the cart.php its self. Here's the code I'm currently using.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if (document.referrer != 'cart.php') {
   document.write('<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Return to the previous page">&laquo; Go back 3</a>');
}
else {
   document.write('<a href="javascript:history.go(-2)" title="Return to the previous page">&laquo; Go back 3</a>');
}

</script>
```

I'm loading this in an Iframe on the cart page as I don't have access to the php for the cart but I can write html to the page to show the links.

Comment: Why tag the question as "Java"? Where does Java come in here?

Answer (score 0):

[`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer) expects a full URI. Give it one:

```
document.referrer != 'http://www.example.com/cart.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up going with. I was able to place this right on the page and with no need for an Iframe. Makes a great generic continue shopping link.
Thanks for the help.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var myArray = [];
myArray[0]= 'http://mydomain.com/shop/cart.php';

for(var i=0;
i<1;
i++) {
if (document.referrer.indexOf(myArray[i]) > -1)
{
document.write('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit; font-size:25px;" href="javascript:history.go(-2)" title="Continue Shopping">&laquo; Continue Shopping</a>');
}
else
{document.write('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit; font-size:25px;" href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Continue Shopping" >&laquo; Continue Shopping</a>');
}
}

</script>
```